# What does a high altitude package in diesel heatings

Tags: diesel, heater

I am currently checking out various camper vans and for one manufacturer there is an option for the diesel heating called "high altitude package" which is supposed to ensure the heating is functioning correctly above 1500m.

- How does such a package work? Are these likely to be software adjustments to the heater controller only or hardware adjustments as well?
- How big of a problem is higher altitude to diesel heating really? (up to ~2000m)

I know that air gets thinner with increasing altitude so it is probably adjusting the ratio of air and diesel, but how?